# are points connected and closed?

Tags: algorithm, point

I have set of 2D points and I need to know it they are connected (ie [0,0] and [1,1] are connected, but [0,0] and [0,2] aren't) and I need to know if they form closed shape (circle, rectangle, any polygon).

finding if points are connected is easy, I actually have algorithm that finds all "structures" formed by multiple points next to each other.

problem is I don't know how to determine if points form closed shape.

this is example array of points:

[image]

please notice that while these points form two closed shapes, I'm looking for biggest possible closed route possible.

I read something about Convex Hulls and Graham scan method, but I'm not really sure how to modify this algorithm to work only with points that are next to each other...

Comment: How are (0,0) and (1,1) connected?

Comment: Don't the points form 3 closed shapes? The two smaller ones and the whole thing.

Comment: If you can find neighbours, then you could simply use a bfs/dfs approach to collecting neighbours until you reach the start node again. Then compare the area of all shapes found, and pick the largest one.

Comment: Things you could look into for ideas: 1. territories in go, you might be able to look for the highest scoring connected set of points/stones. 2. Connectedness of the board. If you color each connected part of the board, the boundaries of regions should be closed paths (I think) 3. Algorithms for finding the largest cycle in a graph, these will probably be slow, but they could work for small datasets and you might find ways to optimize them for your problem.

Comment: my intuition is that if a graph is closed, you should be able find at least one circle. according to this, i think you can combine SCC to locate circles, and use union-find to track it. btw, how do you define some edge cases? for example, is a straight line closed? how curved a curve is to become open?

Comment: How is made the structure that represents your multiple points connected each other? Is simply a list of points or do you have neighborhood info also in it? Do you have separate structures for each separated set of connected points?